# Creating HTML Table with PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

Is there a convention on how to create a table with a structure that resembles an iOS table view or Android `ArrayList` from a PHP array? Basically what I'm trying to do is implement a way to select a row and get the value from that row, something like a key from a database maybe.
When I write `echo "<tr id=data>".$value."</tr>"` within a `foreach` loop, then use JavaScript to print something when it's pressed, it only prints the inner html of the first element in the array. But when I assign the id in the actual html body it works for all rows. I see PHP is really different. Any help would be appreciated!
Code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr id="subject"><?php 
         $subjects = array("IT","Programming","Networks");
        foreach($subjects as $key => $value) {
        echo "<td>"."<a href='index.php'>".$value."</a>"."</td>";
        }     
   ?></tr>
        </table>
    </body>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("subject").onclick = function(){
          console.log(document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML);  
        };

    </script>


</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to do whatever you want. It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong if you don't post code.

Comment: how can i post it?

Comment: How to post code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: i posted the code. basically i just want a way to know what row i select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr id="subject"><?php 
    $subjects = array("IT","Programming","Networks");
    foreach($subjects as $key => $value) {
    echo "<td>"."<a href='index.php' class='column'>".$value."</a>"."</td>";
    }     
  ?></tr>
    </table>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].onclick = function () {
            console.log(this.innerHTML);
        };
    }

</script>
```

Notice I added a `column` class to links, and I'm checking if users click on columns.

Edit: This is assuming I understood your question correctly. Otherwise if your actual code prints multiple rows, with multiple links, and you're trying to get the value of a row, then you shouldn't have multiple `id`s in your html. `id` is unique, `class` is for elements that repeat.

Comment: It works! what you did actually makes a lot of sense. I'm coming from iOS and a bit of Java so php is kind of different. Again I appreciate you accommodating me! Merry Christmas !!

Comment: How would i get the key from the selected element within the javascript tags? I understand these are very simple questions so if you could recommend a book to buy or courses to take i would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. You'll have to write the key first in html somewhere if you want to get it with JavaScript. Like: `echo "<td><span class='key'>".$key."</span><a href='index[.....]/td>";`, and swap `'column'` in that javascript with `'key'`.

Comment: I don't know any books unfortunately. Try to get used to searching on Google is probably the best advice I could give! Good Luck

Comment: thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target` to find out what element the user clicked on.

```js
document.getElementById("subject").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent following the link
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="subject">
    <td><a href="index.php">Programming</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="index.php">IT</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="index.php">Networks</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But the array i have is for testing. In reality the array is going to come from a database. i'm not hardcoding the array. the answer you provided looks good if i would to hardcode it, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: My code doesn't depend on where the array comes from. I just used hard-coded HTML so it would run here.